# Java - Select a number from every square in a 9x9 grid

Tags: java, grid-layout, sudoku

I have a 9x9 sudoku grid and I need to get a random number from every 3x3 square in the grid.

The most awful code would be something like this:

```
    if(square == 0) {
        row = random.nextInt(3);
        col = random.nextInt(3);
    }

    if(square == 1) {
        row = random.nextInt(3);
        col = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
    }
    if(square == 2) {
        row = random.nextInt(3);
        col = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
    }
    if(square == 3) {
        row = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
        col = random.nextInt(3);
    }
    if(square == 4) {
        row = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
        col = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
    }
    if(square == 5) {
        row = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
        col = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
    }
    if(square == 6) {
        row = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
        col = random.nextInt(3);
    }
    if(square == 7) {
        row = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
        col = random.nextInt(3) + 3;
    }
    if(square == 8) {
        row = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
        col = random.nextInt(3) + 6;
    }
```

where `square` is the index of the square in the grid (`square` = 0,1,...,8)

I cannot figure out how to write it in a better way.

Some ideas? Thanks

Comment: I suggest you look at the pattern of row, column, and square indexes. It might help if you draw a big sudoku puzzle where you can label each cell with these three indexes. Can you see any patterns? Try to create a formula that calculates the square index from given row and column indexes. Also, from the square index, make a formula that gives the minimum and maximum row or column.

Comment: When you find the patterns for these formulas, you should be able to simplify your code to a for loop which use them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm trying to figure out. row, col and square can be a number from 0 to 8. When square is `< 3` I don't need to change the row, when is `>= 3 && < 6` I need to make the row bigger by 3 and when is `>=6 && < 9` I need to make the row bigger by 6.

Comment: So notice that you are increasing row by a multiple of 3 (i.e. 0, 3, or 6). Can you determine that multiplier directly from `square`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think I can using modulo or divider, but I don't know how :/

Comment: You are on the right track. Look more closely at this pattern: for `square` == 0, 1, or 2, add `0*3 = 0` to `row`, for `square` == 3, 4, or 5, add `1*3 = 3` to `row`, and for `square` == 6, 7, or 8, add `2*3 = 3` to `row`.

Comment: You mean `2*3 = 6` and it looks like I should divide. Something like `row = random.nextInt(3) + (square / 3)......`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. And yes, dividing by 3 gives you the multiplier. To finish you need to multiple by 3 to get the amount to increase by: `row = random.nextInt(3) + (square / 3) * 3`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks. Now I get it, even someone has already written the answer for me.

Comment: Note that the column is similar, except you use % instead of /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for any square size. In your case is 3x3, so size is 3.

```
int size = 3;
row = random.nextInt(size) + (square / size) * size;
col = random.nextInt(size) + (square % size) * size;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
int[] rowAdd = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6 };
int[] colAdd = new int[] { 0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6 };
row = random.nextInt(3) + rowAdd[square];
col = random.nextInt(3) + colAdd[square];
```

Put in one array values which should be added to variable `row`, name it `rowAdd`. In second array `colAdd` put variable which should be added to `col`.
Finally, use `square` like the index to fetch correct value for addition.

Of course, arrays `rowAdd` and `colAdd` should be part of the method. (It is vast of time and memory to create new arrays every time when you call the method). These arrays should be class related, so they should be `static`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for all things in once

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initializing arrays
        int[][] grid = new int[9][9];
        int[] numbers = new int[9];

        //populating grid
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*10);
            }
        }

        //printing grid
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();

        int counter = 0;
        //first and second loops counts for 0,3,6
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i += 3) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j += 3) {
                //after taking i or j values(which must be either 0,3 or 6) goes for 3x3 parts and saving those numbers in number array
                for(int t = i; t < i+3; t++) {
                    for(int k = j; k < j+3; k++) {
                        numbers[counter] = grid[t][k];
                        counter++;
                    }
                }

                //you can pick randomly from numbers array here

                //showing which numbers picked
                for(int t = 0; t < 9; t++) {
                    System.out.print(numbers[t]);
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't significantly better than the `if...else` chain.

Comment: I am looking for something shorter.

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu do you using `multi-dimensional array` to observe grid or?

Comment: Yes. I have an `int[][]` fot the grid

Comment: @ValentinEmilCudelcu ok let me edit answer for it then.

Comment: @GürtuğGüngör No problem. Thanks.